# Android screen resolution 540px x 960px drawable folder issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, screen-resolution, android-drawable

My code has 5 drawable folders `(drawable, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-sw330dp)`. Each one is used for different screen densities. I have tested each resolution and adjusted accordingly. The only problem so far is that when I test the application on a Droid RAZR, my shapes are drawn incorrectly. The screen size for that particular phone is 540px x 960px.

I have tried three different drawable folder names:

1) `drawable-sw330dp`

2) `drawable-sw540dp`

3) `drawable-sw225dp` << This was suggested by @CommonsWare below

None are adjusting to the xml files that are stored within. It seems like the phone is using the drawable-hdpi instead of going into the specific (sw) folder. Is there another way to make sure that the phone references the right folder?

[image]

Example xml file that draws the shapes (used as a background):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/menu_active" />

        <padding android:left="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="135"
        android:pivotX="96.5%"
        android:pivotY="82%"
        android:toDegrees="45" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#000" />

            <padding android:left="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Comment: Which size of screen?

Comment: @SciJoker the screen size that needs to be fixed is 540px x 960px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `drawable-w330dp-normal` works for the Droid RAZR. Just create the folder and store the modified drawable there.

Answer (score 1):

[The DROID RAZR's screen density should be ~256ppi](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_droid_razr_xt912-4101.php). Motorola probably put it in the `-hdpi` density bucket as a result. The shortest width, therefore, would be 225dp, which is smaller than any of your `-swNNNdp` resource sets.

Comment: I renamed the folder to drawable-sw225dp with no result. Looks like it still using the drawable-hdpi settings even with the smaller dp

Answer (score 0):

Put image resources for MOtorola RAZR in folder: drawable-hdpi

Android supported next formats for drawable assets:

1)`drawable-ldpi`

2)  `drawable-mdpi`

3)`drawable-hdpi`

4)`drawable-xhdpi`

5)`drawable-xxhdpi`

Comment: It's not the images that are the problem. The custom shapes that are being drawn are scaled wrong. Those shapes are in the xml files within the drawable folders, each with different dimensions to account for the different screen densities.

Comment: "The custom shapes that are being drawn are scaled wrong" -- a `ShapeDrawable` is density- and size-independent by nature, at least if you use `dp` for things like corner radii.

Comment: @CommonsWare the dimensions that are causing the problem deal with the rotation of one of the shapes. The pivotX attribute uses percentages rather than dp. More code was posted above to show an example.